# Getting "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.AuthCookies_Update' " Error When Running DNN from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

Im trying to run DNN 9.4.1 from Visual Studio.

And Im gettin the following error;

**"progress":54,"details":"ERROR:Could not find stored procedure dbo.AuthCookies_Update"**

Firstly Ive created dnndev.me database and Ive checked and completed the permissions.

Ive created an app pool on iis named dnndev.me and Ive set the path like ...\Dnn.Platform-9.4.1\Website

Ive checked the folder permissions.

After that Ive run the project from Visual Studio.

In the first step Ive filled Account Informations properly.

In the second step when creating stored procedures, dbo.AuthCookies_Update couldnt be  created

[error-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgsPb.png)

The way Ive tried to solve the error but I couldnt success is;

Ive created a new database with the same name (dnndev.me) and the same permissions

Ive created an app pool with the same name and the same path with controling folder permissions

And I've commented the lines following on the Visual Studio

**( ...\Dnn.Platform-9.4.1\Website\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider --> 09.02.00.SqlProvider file)**

[commented-lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBStf.png)

Before running project on Visual Studio I've create that procedure on SSMS and it has been created successfully

[succeeded-command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nibW5.png)

Then when I run the project Ive got the same error and when I checked the database I couldnt see dbo.AuthCookies_Update on the Stored Procedure files

Ive checked out about this error, its a common error I guess.

I hope there is someone who can help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you are trying to do.

Are you trying to compile and run DNN with VS?  If so, you probably need to do some other things, too.  Building DNN is not recommended.  So ... what exactly are you trying to do?

I'm not sure why you are looking for that stored procedure, unless you are looking because the error is that it doesn't exist?

When you "install" DNN, it builds out the database with tables, stored procedures, etc.  That is the first step of doing an install, and it's not going to run unless you've installed it properly.

To install DNN on a local machine, give nvQuickSite a try.  It will do all of that work for you.

Still, why are you doing this with VS?  It's really not the thing to do.  But, it might make more sense if I understaood what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: We want to use DNN for our new project, its something like CMS portal. We want to develope our modules on it or some developments like that. Thats why we need to run DNN on VS.

We have searched a lot, there is build.ps1 file and we need to run this file from a Powershell Terminal before run the DNN project. Ive done but error again.

What would you suggest at that point? How can I run and debug DNN for my project?

Comment: The best approach is to install DNN locally, and then use VS to build any modules or extensions that you need.

If you look around you will find templates and other starter projects to help you get going.

NONE of this requires that you build, compile or do anything with the DNN core.  That way, you can upgrade DNN and keep you developemental activities without problems.